# What kind of encoder is suitable for AVIREAD in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, ffmpeg

I have a raw video (no header, just Y-channel).
I want do some denoise algorithm on this video.
I convert this raw video by useing ffmpeg with several encoders.
But fail to open with function AVIREAD.

> Error using aviread, Unable to locate decompressor to decompress video stream

r210        Uncompressed RGB 10-bit
v210        Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
v308        Uncompressed packed 4:4:4
v410        Uncompressed 4:4:4 10-bit
y41p        Uncompressed YUV 4:1:1 12-bit
yuv4        Uncompressed packed 4:2:0
mjpeg       MJPEG (Motion JPEG)

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -pix_fmt gray -i WKA00002.y -c:v v308 WKA00002_UnCompAVI.avi
```

What kind of encoder is suitable for AVIREAD in Matlab?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "On UNIX® platforms, filename must be an uncompressed AVI file." http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/aviread.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVIREAD has been removed from the latest versions of MATLAB. Use VIDEOREADER instead.

Motion JPEG AVI is supported by VideoReader.

if you want to try other formats, first check that the file can be opened using Windows Media Player? If so, use VideoReader to try and read the file. If this does not work, can you provide a link to the file that you are using?

Hope this helps.

Dinesh

Comment: I have a mex file.It is use aviobj as input.
So, I can't use VideoReader.
I know VideoReader is better.
Thank you~

Comment: In that case, Motion JPEG AVI would be a safe choice I would assume. Make sure that even if  it fails with aviread, ensure that the file opens with media player or VLC. I have had issues where some uncompressed RGB files I wrote out with FFMPEG could not be played back using VLC which also uses FFMPEG.